# Getting complete attribute table in output feature class through ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, attribute-table, iterator

[image]

I'm creating a tool with ModelBuilder and whenever I run it, it creates an output however the output feature class has an empty attribute table, which I need.

Comment: The dissolve tool will empty the table. You could try Spatial Join tool after Dissolve

Comment: What does `Service_Locations_Intersect.shp` look like?  If it is as you expected then still show us that, and the parameters you are using in the Dissolve step.